# I have p12 certificate when i am trying to convert it to cert.pem and key.pem. Key.pem is empty

Tags: openssl, certificate, pem, p12

I am running following commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certficate.p12 -nokeys -out certficate.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in certficate.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out certficate_key.pem
```

My **certficate_key.pem** file is empty.

Comment: -nocerts means no certificates in the output. Please try without this option

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too. I do not know the reason, but using this website to convert the certificate did the trick:

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

It will create just one file, but if you open it, both the key and crt will be there.